# Duplicate ChangeSet IDs after Liquibase update

Tags: liquibase

I want to update my Spring Boot (2.7.x) project with liquibase version 4.9.1 to latest Spring Boot version (containing Liquibase 4.21.1).

Now I got following exception when booting up my system:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation was unsuccessful:
     840 change sets had duplicate identifiers
```

That relates to the structure of my liquibase xml files: In order to define the dependencies within a multi-module project they are referencing each other:

```
# db/migration/changes/second.changelog.xml
...
<include file="/db/migration/changes/first.changelog.xml" />
...
```

Before the upgrade it worked well, now I get the exception above.

What I already tried:

- Skipping the duplicate change set validation: I breakpointed in liquibase.changelog.visitor.ValidatingVisitor::validationPassed() and just returned true. Outcome was that the scripts are indeed executed twice and I get an SQL error, that tables already existed.
- Removing the includes: That worked, I could resolve the duplications here, but then liquibase is not executing these files in the right order. Furthermore my itests broke because the dependencies of the scripts were missing.
- Removing the includes and listing the changelogs explicitely inside of my db.changelog-master.yaml works. But this is not an option because I need to do same for intration tests and activating/deactivating single changelogs by spring profiles won't work with this "monolithic" configuration.

My question now: Has there been some new feature which handles duplicates differently? How can I fix the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Liquibase-Team fixed a bug in 4.19.1. Currently there is a discussion if that should be a feature ;-)

https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/3881#issuecomment-1843935985

There will be a new flag in the newest version which enables this "feature" again:

```
-Dliquibase.allowDuplicatedChangesetIdentifiers=true
```

Until this is released, downgrading to 4.19.0 works for me.